# Tag synonyms page layout bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tags

The [tag synonyms page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/wifi/synonyms) seems like it has a layout bug.  The text in the body is very close to the margin.  See screenshot:

[image: Tag synonym page screenshot]

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.